# figure in single column where the text is in double column (in the same page)

Tags: two-column, ieeetran

I am using IEEE conference style in latex where the page limit is only 1. I have only one figure that spans two columns, and the text is written in two-column as usual. I used figure*, but that is moving my figure on the next page. Also the package 'cuted' and 'widetext' showing some error and not performing properly in my case. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community!

As I am quite new to TeX.se myself, I am not entirely sure my suggestion will solve your problem.

You could try the [sttools package collection](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sttools), especially the stfloats-package might be worth a look. The options this solution will give you are still very limited. Your best bet would be placing the image at the bottom of the page (the `bp` flag after the figure*-environment).

## Edit

Apparently, the placement of the figure in your source document is important. Placing it higher prevents it from being pushed to the next page.

Here is a Minimal Working Example (MWE):

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[bp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8em]{example-image}
\caption{Some caption for your image.}
\end{figure*}

\section{First Section}

\kant[1-2]

\section{Second Section}

\kant[3-4]

\end{document}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: full-width image in a IEEE Conference Paper]

I hope this helps.